# Macro to change a date from American to English?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How can I change all dates on a sheet from American format (`mm/dd/yyyy`) to English format (`dd/mm/yyyy`)? Is there a way to do this with a VBA macro?

Comment: Are you wanting to change how a string is stored or how the date value is displayed?  Internally excel stores dates as doubles, regardless of the display format you choose.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub enFormat()    
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells you want to change, open their format dialog (on old versions it was Ctrl+1) and change it.